# how to deal with [.map is not a function]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

> I'm learning React Framework. When i try to fetch from my api using setState **.map** function dont work. It render **"data.map is not a function"**

This is the only Method i know:

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          name: "secret",
          email: "secret",
          datas: []
        };
      }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { name, password} = this.state;

    fetch(
      `http://localhost:3000/api/user/account?username=${username}&email=${email}`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(getdata => {
        this.setState({ datas: getdata });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

render() {
    const { datas } = this.state;
    const repoItems = datas.map(data => (
      <div key={data.id}>
       <p>{data.name}</p>
       <p>{data.email}</p>
      </div>

    ));

    return (
      <div>
        {datas}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Did I wrote my code wrong or is there any other method beside from this

Comment: are you sure the `getData` you are getting is an array, can you print it and verify as .map is only for arrays

Comment: show the result what you get.. if you get [] it will work fine with map.. if you getting {} directly play with your result like this.state.datas.name

Comment: i think **getData** is not an array but I'm fetching **datas** that I indicate as an array so that i can use **datas.map()**

Comment: In general, if you get "`x.map` is not a function" it means that `x` is not an array. It's pretty straightforward to debug from there on out.

Comment: Well if `getdata` isn't an array then you need to change `this.setState({ datas: getdata })` into something like `this.setState({ datas: getdata.datas })` or process the API response some other way. What exactly *is* returned?

Comment: The problem was my credentials. The authentication don't match.

Answer (score 1):

From the top view everything seems fine with your code. `map` will only run on arrays and I can see that you are setting default state to array as well. However the problem may lies when you attempt to set the state after getting response from `fetch` call

```
  fetch(
      `http://localhost:3000/api/user/account?username=${username}&email=${email}`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(getdata => {
        this.setState({ datas: getdata });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Here you need to make sure that whatever you are setting data, it should be an array. So in case you are not getting the array in the response set the value which is actually an array and in case the response is empty set an empty array in state instead, something like below

```
 // may be array is a property of response
 this.setState({ datas: getdata.array });
 // may be getdata is empty
 this.setState({ datas: getdata || [] });
```

Comment: i will try some test if this works because nor of that syntax response an error, but if i do **this.setState({ datas: getData.array || [] })** works

Comment: @codeformoney Again: what is the contents of `getData`? Do you not realize that simply using `getData.array || []` will obviously work because `getData.array` most likely doesn't exist in the first place?

Comment: @codeformoney as Chris G rightly pointed out you need to know what getData returns and then look for the array which you want to set in state

Comment: The problem was my credentials. The authentication don't match.